# tkinter upload image and save it to local directory

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the user to select a file an then save it on a local directory.

This is my current code.

```
def open_file(self):
    curr_directory = os.getcwd()
    self.file_path = askopenfilename(initialdir=curr_directory, title="Select Image", filetypes=[('Image Files', '*.jpg')])
    if self.file_path is not None:
        pass

def uploadFiles(self):
    curr_directory = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(curr_directory + "/images")

    completeName = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "test.jpg")

    file = open(self.file_path, 'r')

    file1 = open(completeName, "w")
    file1.write(file.read())
    file.close()
    file1.close()
    os.chdir(curr_directory)
```

Although it creates the file, it is empty. Any help?

Comment: For image file, you need to use `rb` mode for reading and `wb` for writing.  BTW, you can simply use [shutil.copyfile()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) to copy file.

Comment: that fixed the issue.. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I believe I can help with the saving. To save it use this:

```
img = open_file() #Whatever the given image is
save_path = "/images"
file_name = "test.jpg"
complete_name = os.path.join(save_path, file_name)
img.save(complete_name) #This adds it to the directory
```